# How to set up Tomcat session state in AWS EC2 for failover and security

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

I am setting up a Tomcat application in EC2. For reliability, I am running two or more instances. If one server goes down, my users should be redirected to the other instance. This suggests that session state should be kept in an external source, or mirrored between the servers.

AWS offers a hosted service, Elasticache, which seems like it would work well. I even found a nice library, [memcached-session-manager](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager). However, I soon ran into some issues.

1. Unless someone can convince me otherwise, I need the session states to be encrypted in transit. Otherwise someone could intercept the network traffic and pretend to be someone else on my site. I don't see any built-in Amazon method to keep traffic off the internet. (Is peering available here?)
2. The library mentioned earlier does have Redis support with SSL, but it does not support a Redis cluster. Someone put in a pull request for this but it has not been incorporated and this library is a complex build. I may talk myself into living without the cluster, but that puts us back at a single point of failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Tomcat is running on EC2 in your VPC, and ElastiCache is in your VPC. Your [AWS VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) is an isolated network. Nobody can intercept the traffic between the EC2 and Elasticache servers unless your VPC network becomes compromised in some way.
2. If you want to use Redis instead, with SSL connections, then I believe at this time you would need a Tomcat Session Manager implementation that uses Jedis. [This one](https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager/issues) uses Jedis, but you would need to upgrade the version of Jedis it uses in order to use SSL connections.

Comment: I am planning to use this one: https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager which supports non-clustered Redis.I know AWS recommends the one you did but it is not being maintained at all.

Comment: I didn't realize that one also used Jedis. Sounds like it should work. I definitely recommend Reds instead of Memcached, but I don't recommend forcing encryption on everything inside your VPC unless you have to for regulatory compliance.

Comment: I figured it would do no harm to use SSL here as it is easy. Will there be huge performance hit if I do?